# If the typed password does not match the logged in user password show validation

Tags: php, laravel

Hi there how can I put validation to appear bottom input with red on Laravel

```
  public function initiateAccountDeletion(Request $request){


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'password' => 'required'
        ]); 

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json(['success' => 0, 'message' => 'Could not initite the account deletion because of validation fail!'], 422);
        } 

        if ((Hash::check($request['password'], Auth::user()->password))) {

            $user = Auth::user();
            $code = $this->generateDeletionCode();

            UserDeletionCode::create(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                                      'code'    => $code]);

            Mail::to(Auth::user()->email)->send(new AccountDeletion($user, $code));

            return redirect()->back()->with(['status' => Lang::get('general.delete_account_success_message')]); 
        }else{  
            return redirect()->back()->with(['errori' => Lang::get('general.please_enter_current_pass')]); 

        }  
    }
```

And here is my input inside my form but  i am showing only this part

```
   <div class="form-group floating-label {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                                <input class="form-control" name="password"  id="regular2" type="password" required>
                                <label for="regular2">@lang('android.user_login_email_password')</label>
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif 
                            </div>
```

So what I need is the error to appear  to this `{{ $errors->first('password') }}`

Answer (score 0):

you have typo

```
return redirect()->back()->with(['errori' => Lang::get('general.please_enter_current_pass')]);
```

it should be

```
return redirect()->back()->with(['errors' => Lang::get('general.please_enter_current_pass')]);
```

Comment: no this is working as an alert but I don't need this I need how I explained above to be inside that help-block

Comment: @lilo a sta je prikazano kad  bude error, jel blank ili ??

Comment: Can we keep it English, please? Thanks (Also, imho, a little comment should be enough to point out a typo)